# NSString of comma separated days to NSDate calculate closest day to current day

Tags: ios, json, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string like this 13, 27, 29 representing days of the month I want to separate them like below into date objects

```
mayString = [mayString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

I then want to be able to work out which of these days i.e 13 or 27 or 29 is closest to todays date which obviously taking the above dates would be 27 as the next closest date to current date.

I can grab current day using the below but really stuck on how to get the logic to do this?

```
//Grab current day from sys date
NSDateFormatter *dayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dayFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString *dayString = [dayFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

I have a partial completed solution but it doesnt seem to give me the correct result of what index in the array is closest to current day (sepDates is an array)

```
sepDates = [mayString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

//Day string is todays date i.e 16 (16th)
    NSDate *dayFromString = [dayFormatter dateFromString:dayString];
    NSLog(@"Day from string %@", dayFromString);

    double min = [dayFromString timeIntervalSinceDate:[sepDates objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog(@"Min %f", min);

//I then want to calculate which of the dates in the sepDates array at index is closest to todays current day 16

    int minIndex = 0;
    for (int d = 1; d < [sepDates count]; ++d)
    {
        double currentmin = [dayFromString timeIntervalSinceDate:[sepDates objectAtIndex:d]];
        if (currentmin < min) {
            min = currentmin;
            minIndex = d;

            NSLog(@"minIndex = %d", minIndex);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you check that your `dayString` object is correctly formatted by logging its value? `NSDateFormatter` does weird stuff sometimes.

Comment: @Maarten yes dayString shows todays day i.e 16 which is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. dayString shouldn't be a string, it should be NSInteger
2. While iterating through your array with dates, also convert all strings to integer (for example, `[currentDayString integerValue]`)

Actual algorithm of searching the closest day would be to iterate through your initial array and find abs of difference between values in array and current day. Store those differences in separate array. Find minimum value in the second array. Location (index) of the minimal difference will be the same as location of closest day in the first array.

Here is the code snippet from the question that gives correct minIndex

```
NSArray *sepDates = @[@"13", @"15", @"27", @"29"];

NSDateFormatter *dayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dayFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString *dayString = [dayFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSDate *dayFromString = [dayFormatter dateFromString:dayString];
NSLog(@"Day from string %@", dayFromString);


NSInteger min = [[sepDates lastObject] integerValue]; //or set it to some large int
NSLog(@"Min %d", min);
int minIndex = 0;
for (int d = 1; d < [sepDates count]; ++d)
{
    NSInteger currentmin = [sepDates[d] integerValue] - [dayString integerValue];
    NSLog(@"Current min: %d", currentmin);
    //currentmin must be positive since you need next closest day
    if (currentmin > 0 && currentmin < min) {
        min = currentmin;
        minIndex = d;

        NSLog(@"minIndex = %d", minIndex);

    }
}
```

Comment: I have some of this code already edited above however it doesnt seem to give me the correct result?

Comment: this codes is spot on however my array of sepDates = [mayString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; crashes. I can log the index of the array to see if it seperated the array of strings, using your array its fine. Is that a C array?

Comment: No, that is Objective-C NSArray. Probably, your array contains non-integer values. After you create an array by sepDates = [mayString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];  print it with NSLog to verify that it has only integers.

Comment: no worries never seen an array declared like that so it threw me so your array is an array of ints mine is still an array of strings so I will convert those to ints then. Cheers

Comment: My array is also an array of strings (see, for example, this tutorial: http://blog.bignerdranch.com/398-objective-c-literals-part-1). I'm converting all string values later, using integerValue method of NSString.

Comment: ah that makes sense sorry not seen this until now. I thought they looked like strings but got confused anyway your code is spot on so thanks!

Comment: sorry using my array of comma seperated strings the log outputs sepDates (
    18,
    27,
    29
) But log says minIndex is 1 it should say 0 as today is the 17th the next date is the 18th so it should say minIndex = 0 no?
2013-05-17 12:24:08.826 App-SCC[4751:907] minIndex = 1

Comment: as I test I changed your array of string dates to sepDates = @[@"18", @"20", @"27", @"29"]; and I also get minIndex = 1 when it should be 0 as 18 is next date not 20

Comment: it seems to ignore the first object in the array?

Comment: dont worry me being an idiot should be for (int d = 0; d < [sepDates count]; ++d) not int d = 1 duhhhh sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your dates and calculate the time from the current target and store that date if it is less than previously calculated or if nothing has been calculated (i.e. first element). The results from that will give you the answer.

Comment: I gather I need to Iterate over the seperated days I am more stuck on once days strings are seperated what they are stored as and then how to compare to get result.

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

After you have separated the dates. convert them to int and add them to a mutable index set.

then, get todays date as string with format "dd" using date formatter, convert todays date (date string) to int and then add that date to the mutable index set.

NSMutableIndexSet is auto sorted.

then do this

`NSInteger closestDateAsInt = [indexSet indexGreaterThanIndex:''today's date as int"];`

this will give u the closest next date.

Once u have the closest date's int value. Convert it to date using date components.

Hope this helps. Cheers.